# Hacer una declaración typedef que no sea a su vez una definición

Tags: c++

Contexto, lo estoy preguntando por el ejercicio 2 de la sección "2.7 Ejercicios" del libro "El lenguaje de Programación C++" (segunda edición, Bjarne Stroustrup)
Básicamente dadas unas declaraciones o declaracion-definicion (osea, una declaración que es a su vez una definición) tengo que, para las primeras, darles una definición y, para las segundas, hacer una declaración que no sea a su vez una definición.
La duda me surgió con esto:

```
typedef complejo punto;
```

Al principio pensé en:

```
typedef extern complejo punto;
```

La idea siendo que si la entidad a la que se refiere punto es complejo pero complejo tiene su definición en otro lado entonces la expresión que puse ahí sería solo una declaración. Aunque siento que esta lógica es incorrecta y además no funciona, je.

La otra cosa que se me ocurrió fue:

```
extern typedef punto;
```

Que, en mi opinión, tenía mucha más pinta de ser correcto que lo que había propuesto antes.
Pero cuando lo fui a probar de la siguiente forma:

```
//arch1.cpp
extern typedef punto;
```

y

```
//arch2.cpp
struct complejo {
    int r; //parte real
    int i; //parte imaginaria
};
typedef complejo punto;
```

compilando con `g++ arch1.cpp arch2.cpp`
Me dió un error:

```
arch1.cpp:1:16: error: `punto` does not name a type
    1 | extern typedef punto;
```

Y también me acabo de encontrar en una página algo que dice que las declaraciones typedef no pueden ser static o extern.
Entonces, ¿cómo es la mano? ¿cómo se puede hacer? ¿dónde estoy metiendo la pata?

Answer (score 0):

[`typedef`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) crea un alias. Punto importante:

> The typedef specifier cannot be combined with any other specifier except for type-specifiers.

En español: no puede ser combinado con otro especificador excepto con los de tipo. Por esta razón falla.

[`extern`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) te permite referenciar a una variable que vive en otra unidad de traducción.

Independientemente, no existe una solución directa.

Lo que sí puedes hacer, es tener un puntero y crear la instancia más tarde en memoria dinámica, o usar [`optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), disponible en la cabecera [`optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/optional).

Comment: "Además, si la declaración no tiene un inicializador, no es una definición."
Ahí no te sigo
`int a;` es una declaración y una definición.
Declaración porque especifica que el nombre "a" es del tipo "int".
Definición porque esa expresión tal cual está también esta indicando a que entidad se refiere "a" ya que esta asignando una cantidad de memoria apropiada para "a" según el tipo (en este caso "int")
¿ O te entendí mal ? Con inicializador te referís a un valor inicial, ¿cierto?
Por ejemplo: `int a = 4;`

Comment: @Sturm El [inicializador](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) es la asignación. En `int a = 5`, `= 5` es la inicialización. [Más información sobre definición](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)

Comment: Entonces no entiendo porque decís que si la declaración no tiene un inicializador no es una definición.

Comment: "Si la idea original era crear el alias para evitar escribir extern, no queda otra. Debes ser explícito y escribirlo cada vez que sea necesario."

La idea original era convertir de alguna forma `typedef complejo punto;` en algo que fuera solo una declaración. No se sí el ejemplo de código que pusiste cumple con lo pedido con el ejercicio. Ya que ahí lo que es solo declaración es: `extern punto punto1` que significa "la definición de punto1 esta en otro lado" y lo que, **creo**, que tengo que conseguir es algo que sea: "el de que es sinonimo punto esta definido en otro lado"

Comment: Disculpa. Parece que tengo un falso recuerdo de que se podía hacer lo que pides. Ahora lo arreglo.